# C++ crash at try-catch statement

Tags: c++, class, testing, crash, try-catch

So, I'm doing a homework where we have to test our class. We were forbidden to use stl.:) The problem is that at the test_2 the program crashes. It works all until it gets beck to the main try statement. When it should jump to the exception it just crashes. Any idea why is this happening? Thanks in advance! :)

```
void test_2()    //
{
    int tomb[400];
    for(unsigned int j=0;j<400;j++){
        tomb[j]=j;
    }
   cout <<"array loaded \n";

    Buffer<int> test2(40,"test2.txt","w");
    Buffer<int> test21(40,"test21.txt","w");    // 40 meretu buffer

   cout << "bufferek letrehozva \n";

    for(unsigned int j=0;j<400;j++){
        test2[j]=tomb[j];

    }

    cout << "buff loaded \n";
  /*  for(unsigned int j=0;j<400;j++){
       cout << test2[j] << endl;

    } */
    test21=test2;

    cout << "copy constr ran \n";
    unsigned int i=0;
    for(unsigned int j=0;j<400;j++){
        if(i==39){for(i=0;i<40;i++){       //40 size buff
                    test21.printfile(test21[i]);}
                    i=0;}
        else i++;
    }
  throw "gets here";


}
int main()
{

    try
    {
        int number;
        cin >> number;        // nr of the test
        switch (number)
        {
        case 1:
            test_1();     // file_test
            break;

        case 2:
            test_2();   // copyconst_test
            break;     // crashes here

        case 3:
            test_3();
            break;
        }



    }
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (int i)
    {
        cerr << i << endl;
    }
    catch (const char* s)
    {
       cerr << s << endl;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cerr << "*** Nagy baj van! ****" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes :/ whenever it reaches the maximum it doubles its size.

Comment: This can be a lot of things, perhaps your Buffer might be throwing another exception in the destructor? If you comment out the `throw "gets here";` line, what happens?

Comment: Also, catch the std::exception by const reference, i.e. `catch (const exception& e)`.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I made an obj with the size of 40 and loaded it with 400 int. This procedure made the size of the test2 object 720(becuse at overloading it doubles its size) so I made 2 different sized objects equal.

```
Buffer<int> test2(40,"test2.txt","w");
        // first buffer

   cout << "bufferek made\n";

    for(unsigned int j=0;j<400;j++){
        test2[j]=tomb[j];            //load buffer

    }

    Buffer<int> test21(test2.getSize(),"test21.txt","w");   //make the second buffer
```